# How I wait for the a number of objects to be displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm trying to avoid using the sleep function to wait for a page to load with a certain number of the same element. I have 2 elements on a page, I delete one therefore the page needs to wait for the count to go down to one for the test to be successful.

I have tried the following code, however it seems that no matter what number I put for the count, the test always passes. This is to deal with a race condition.

```
foo_page.delete_element
foo_page.section.wait_for_element(count:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding the following line:

```
**foo_page.section.wait_for_element(maximum: 1)**
expect(foo_page.section).to have_element(count: 1)
```